# Query multiple taxonomies group slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace, taxonomy

I have a checkbox function that I'm using for my search query. My problem is the url created when I search.

```
?ct_zipcode=&ct_event_type=birthday&ct_event_type=photovideo-shoot&Venue-search=true
```

When I have multiple taxonomy_names checked I only get the last slug in my search results.

I need my url to be rewritten like:

```
?ct_zipcode=&ct_event_type=birthday%2Cphotovideo-shoot&Venue-search=true
```

Is there an easy way to change my url with rewrite? I've tried a little `str_replace` / `preg_replace` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the input field to `ct_event_type[]` and you'll get the checked values as an array.

---

The HTML part should look like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>"> // for should be the same as checkbox id
        <input
          id="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>"
          name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>"
          type="checkbox"
          style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px"
          value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>" />   // <-- closing input
        <?php echo $t->name; ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

Note the use of `label`.

Comment: I would but I don't want to lose my dynamic checkbox in my form.

Comment: I don't see how this prevents you from changing the name. Change to: `name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>[]"`

Comment: Thanks, but no go. I've tried this earlier and it doesn't change my value to an array because my checkbox is inside a function. It would be a solution if I could change it to an array. I left out some of the function, below is the entire function.

Comment: function ct_search_form_check($name, $taxonomy_name = null) {global $search_values;if (!$taxonomy_name) {$taxonomy_name = $name;}?><?php foreach( get_terms($taxonomy_name, 'hide_empty=0') as $t ) : ?><?php if ($search_values[$name] == $t->slug) { $selected = 'checked="checked"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?><div><input id="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px" <?php echo $selected; ?>value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>"><?php echo $t->name; ?><span style="margin-left:10px"></span></input></div><?php endforeach; ?><?php }

Comment: I looked at your code and I still don't see why you can't just change the name. As an alternative you can change `$name` to contain the `[]`. Maybe unrelated, but you're not using `input` right, I'll post the 'fixed' code in my answer.

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for, so far anyway I try to use [] it will output ?ct_zipcode=&ct_event_type%5B%5D=alumni&ct_event_type%5B%5D=anneverisy&Venue-search=true. I'm using <?php ct_search_form_check('event_type'); ?> in my search-form.php again adding [] returns the same. the function I'm editing is in theme-function.php and I also have tried making changes to the array in my Query multiple taxonomies file. Can you explain "change $name to contain the []" I would like to give that a try.

Comment: Check the value of the `$_GET` on the receiving page. You should get `ct_event_type` as an array. By changing `$name` I meant: `ct_search_form_check('event_type[]');`

Comment: $taxonomies_to_search = array('event_type' => 'Reason for Event','setting' => 'Setting','aminities' => 'Aminities','services' => 'Services','guest' => 'Guest','zipcode' => 'Zipcode'); $search_values = array(); foreach ($taxonomies_to_search as $t => $l) { $var_name = 'ct_'. $t ; if (!empty($_GET[$var_name])) { $search_values[$t] = utf8_encode($_GET[$var_name]);} }$search_values['post_type'] = 'listings'; $search_values['paged'] = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; $search_values['showposts'] = 10; $mode = 'search'; I would chat but I don't have the reputation to do so