# Replace &ct_= with %2c or comma

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I've been wrestling with this function for far to long and I wish I had enough respect to offer a bounty. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Advanced Search Check
function ct_search_form_check($name, $taxonomy_name = null) {
global $search_values;

    if (!$taxonomy_name) {
        $taxonomy_name = $name;
    } ?>
    <?php foreach( get_terms($taxonomy_name, 'hide_empty=0') as $t) : ?>
        <?php if ($search_values[$name] == $t->slug) { $selected = 'checked="checked"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
            <div><input id="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px" <?php echo $selected; ?>value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>"><?php echo $t->name; ?><span style="margin-left:10px"></span></input></div>

           //recently added this part to replace duplicate taxonomy_name in url
           <?php $data = array();
                while (list($name, $t->slug) = each($arr)) {
                   $data[] = "$name";
                }
                echo implode($data); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
}
```

How do I change my output from

> ?ct_zipcode=&ct_event_type=alumni&ct_=anneverisy&ct_setting=ballroom&ct_=bar&Venue-search=true

to

> ?ct_zipcode=&ct_event_type=alumni%2canneverisy&ct_setting=ballroom%2cbar&Venue-search=true

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071332/query-multiple-taxonomies-group-slugs

Comment: Have you tried urlencode?

Comment: John can you post an answer? I'm not familiar with urlencode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. hopefully it will help someone else

```
function ct_search_form_check($name, $taxonomy_name = null) {
global $search_values;

    if (!$taxonomy_name) {
        $taxonomy_name = $name;
    } ?>

<input type="hidden" value=""  name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <?php foreach( get_terms($taxonomy_name, 'hide_empty=0') as $t) : ?>
        <?php if ($search_values[$name] == $t->slug) { $selected = 'checked="checked"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
            <div><input id="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px" <?php echo $selected; ?>value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>"><?php echo $t->name; ?><span style="margin-left:10px"></span></input></div>
           <?php 
           $data = array();
                while (list($name, $t->slug) = each($arr)) {
                   $data[] = "$name";
                }
                echo implode($data); 
                if (!empty($_GET['ct_'])) { 
                    $url = str_replace('&ct_=', '%2c', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
                    header("Location: ?$url");
                } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php 
}
```